# How to stop Application with exception and user message

Tags: android, exception

I want to throw an exception in Android so that the app is shut down and a the user gets the ability to report this error to the developer.

I put this into a UI class:

```
throw new Exception("error...");
```

but I get an unhandled error. When I use `RuntimeException` it wont crash and end my application.

Comment: you can used try and catch block. you can catch exception into catch using yourexceptionobject.printmessage().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put in try ... catch a messagebox that ask to you customer to send an email to developer and on the response you can shut down your application.

```
try {
    ......
} catch (Exception e) {
    dialog.setMessage("Your Message " + e.toString() + ". Send Email?");
dialog.setButtonNegativeText("NO");
dialog.setButtonPositiveText("YES");
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "NoticeDialogFragment");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a user defined exception and throw the exception in the catch block..
     MyOwnExceptionClass.java
    public class MyOwnExceptionClass extends Exception {

```
private int price;

public MyOwnExceptionClass(int price){
    this.price = price;
}

public String toString(){
    return "Price should not be in negative, you are entered" +price;
}
}

 your working class

 public class Client {
 public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
{
   int price = -120;

   if(price < 0)
    throw new MyOwnExceptionClass(price);
  else
  System.out.println("Your age is :"+price);
  }
}
```

Comment: whats the difference between throwing a predefined exception e.g. IllegalStateException or my own exception? If I throw IllegalStateException I dont get the desired behavior (app crashes)